# Spring @Async error handling with database access

Tags: spring

I'm able to intercept Async exceptions using the following class.

I need to register exceptions in a database,is there a way to use autowiring in this class ? It seems not to support it.

(Tried @Controller and @Service, does not work)

```
public class AsyncExceptionHandler  implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private IDBEventService dbEventService;

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
        System.out.println("Exception message - " + throwable.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Method name - " + method.getName());
        for (Object param : obj) {
            System.out.println("Parameter value - " + param);
        }

        dbEventService.recordEvent("Something happened");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to log the exception and configure a database appender for the logger.